# How to style HTML elements outside of DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

Would like to find out if there is a solution to style non DOM elements within HTML. My problem is the following:

Wish to change mouse cursor hover over  tag, but because it is a non DOM element, it cannot be achieved (according to previous findings). It only, and only accepts the following code:

```css
area {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

However, I wish to use this:

```css
area {
    cursor: url("https://img.icons8.com/dusk/64/000000/cursor.png"), pointer;
}
```

When the cursor moves inside the area, it supposed to change its icon to the custom one.

Although, I've read that it might be possible using JSX?* It would be for a browser game, where it is crucial to keep the custom cursor at all times (and not revert back to the one that is used by the system)

*Unfortunately SVG is not an option.

Tried modifying global CSS parameters, html/javascript codes beforehand. As you might've guessed, this goes beyond my html knowledge, and browsing through hundreds of webpages (stack overflow included), did not solve my problem.

Code that I'm trying to modify:

HTML

```
<div>
    <map id="world" name="world">
        <area shape="circle" alt="Africa" title="Africa" coords="682,462,97" href="AllItems.aspx" target="_self" onmouseover="afr.style.visibility='visible'; afr.src='africa.png';" onmouseout="afr.style.visibility='hidden';" />
        <area shape="circle" alt="Americas" title="Americas" coords="228,198,123" href="AllItems.aspx" target="_self" onmouseover="ame.style.visibility='visible'; ame.src='americas.png';" onmouseout="ame.style.visibility='hidden';" />
        <area shape="circle" alt="Asia/Pacific" title="Asia/Pacific" coords="1110,412,122" href="AllItems.aspx" target="_self" onmouseover="asi.style.visibility='visible'; asi.src='asiapacific.png';" onmouseout="asi.style.visibility='hidden';" />
        <area shape="circle" alt="Europe" title="Europe" coords="627,136,98" href="AllItems.aspx" target="_self" onmouseover="eur.style.visibility='visible'; eur.src='europe.png';" onmouseout="eur.style.visibility='hidden';" />
    </map>
    <img alt="Africa" style="position:absolute;top:559px;left:779px;visibility:hidden;" id="afr" src="africa.png" />
    <img alt="Americas" style="position:absolute;top:321px;left:351px;visibility:hidden;" id="ame" src="americas.png" />
    <img alt="Asia/Pacific" style="position:absolute;top:534px;left:1232px;visibility:hidden;" id="asi" src="asiapacific.png" />
    <img alt="Europe" style="position:absolute;top:234px;left:725px;visibility:hidden;" id="eur" src="europe.png" />
    <img id="worldmap" alt="world map" src="http://fivebs.net/fiddle/worldmap.png" usemap="#world" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
#worldmap {
    position: relative;
    cursor: url("https://img.icons8.com/wired/64/000000/cursor.png"), auto;
}
area {
    cursor: url("https://img.icons8.com/dusk/64/000000/cursor.png"), pointer;
}
```

The goal would be to have the mouse cursor change, when you hover over the circle areas, within the image map (and not be the default one).

Comment: Looks like your code already does this, as-is.  Guess I'm not seeing something.  Could be be more detailed about what you're expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer: Just demonstrating that your code seems to do exactly what you were wanting.

```css
#worldmap {
    position: relative;
    cursor: url("https://img.icons8.com/wired/64/000000/cursor.png"), auto;
}
area {
    cursor: url("https://img.icons8.com/dusk/64/000000/cursor.png"), pointer;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <map id="world" name="world">
        <area shape="circle" alt="Africa" title="Africa" coords="682,462,97" href="AllItems.aspx" target="_self" onmouseover="afr.style.visibility='visible'; afr.src='africa.png';" onmouseout="afr.style.visibility='hidden';" />
        <area shape="circle" alt="Americas" title="Americas" coords="228,198,123" href="AllItems.aspx" target="_self" onmouseover="ame.style.visibility='visible'; ame.src='americas.png';" onmouseout="ame.style.visibility='hidden';" />
        <area shape="circle" alt="Asia/Pacific" title="Asia/Pacific" coords="1110,412,122" href="AllItems.aspx" target="_self" onmouseover="asi.style.visibility='visible'; asi.src='asiapacific.png';" onmouseout="asi.style.visibility='hidden';" />
        <area shape="circle" alt="Europe" title="Europe" coords="627,136,98" href="AllItems.aspx" target="_self" onmouseover="eur.style.visibility='visible'; eur.src='europe.png';" onmouseout="eur.style.visibility='hidden';" />
    </map>
    <img alt="Africa" style="position:absolute;top:559px;left:779px;visibility:hidden;" id="afr" src="africa.png" />
    <img alt="Americas" style="position:absolute;top:321px;left:351px;visibility:hidden;" id="ame" src="americas.png" />
    <img alt="Asia/Pacific" style="position:absolute;top:534px;left:1232px;visibility:hidden;" id="asi" src="asiapacific.png" />
    <img alt="Europe" style="position:absolute;top:234px;left:725px;visibility:hidden;" id="eur" src="europe.png" />
    <img id="worldmap" alt="world map" src="http://fivebs.net/fiddle/worldmap.png" usemap="#world" />
</div>
```

Comment: In theory yes. That being said, for some reason, it doesn't work (in Firefox). As I mentioned earlier, it only accepts the "pointer/help/none/etc." attribute, not a custom URL. @Tibrogargan

Comment: Actually, you didn't mention it earlier - well, you didn't mention it's specifically a Firefox issue.  Probably want to tag the question with that and explicitly mention it in the question.

Comment: That's it, I don't think it is specific to Firefox, that is what I'd like to find out. And if it is indeed browser related, than how to solve it? @Tibrogargan My knowledge is limited on these things, so I've no idea, sorry.

Comment: Firefox is supposed to support `cursor: url`.  See [Can I Use CSS3 UI](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-cursors-newer)